# C# доступ к записи фала

Tags: c#, io, visual-studio

Как решить проблему доступа к файлу: программа вываливалась с необрабатываемым исключением. 
Я сделал такую функцию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставил цикл до тех пор, пока эта проверка не вернет false:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но теперь программа уходит в вечный цикл. Как решить данные проблемы?

Comment: 1. Оформите код в нормальном виде, чтобы можно было что-то понять.
2. Напишите, что конкретно вам нужно сделать с файлом, прочитать данные из него, записать или еще что-то, проблем с доступом не должно быть - подозреваю, что вы не закрываете его после открытия, но в любом случае вариант с циклом и проверкой доступа излишен.

Comment: Я все еще пытаюсь разобрать эту кашу. Не получается у меня работать с местным редактором. Смысл что в том куске кода я создаю несколько каталогов, а в одном из них - текстовый файл и сразу же пытаюсь в него записать одну строчку - вываливается ошибка доступа.

Comment: Для форматирования кода в подобающий вид необходимо всего лишь выделить его и нажать в редакторе кнопку 010101

Comment: И так, и этак - все равно в одну кучу лепится

Comment: В вашем коде проблема опять таки с потоками: вы сперва создаете файл методом Create (но совершенно не думатее о том, что в данном случае файл не только создается, но к нему еще и создается и открывается поток - данный метод его как раз и возвращает). Для записи данных используйте СОЗДАННЫЙ поток, а не снова пытайтесь в ОТКРЫТЫЙ файл писать что-то.

Comment: Удалите строки из вашей ф-ции начиная с File.Create вместе с циклом! Оставьте только File.WriteAllText... и думаю ваши проблемы на етом кончаться.

Comment: Я о потоках только краем уха слышал, не могли бы вы подсказать как в контексте данного кода использовать закрыть\ использовать открытый поток? Если это возможно, конечно.

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания файла и записи в него данных можно использовать массу вариантов, но как по мне самый простой использовать класс [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx). У него есть масса методов, но для вашего примера сойдет [этот](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) например. По ссылке есть и примеры использования и описание возможных "експетионов", и масса дополнительной информации (оно и не мудрено - мсдн все таки). Единственное, что хочется добавить - работа с потоками. По примерам из ссылок видно, что при создании потока для чтения или записи файла используется конструкция "юзинг". Не знаю, насколько вы осведомлены об этой возможности языка, но либо используйте такую конструкцию, либо закрывайте "руками" созданные вами потоки.

Comment: Я уже натыкался на эту страницу в мсдн, но отбросил ее за излишней сложностью. Но, если ее мне здесь предложили, я еще раз попробую в ней разобратся, большое спасибо.

Comment: Не за что - задавайте конкретные вопросы и вам помогут непременно здесь.

Comment: Я так понимаю мой посл коментарий таки решил ваши проблемы? :)

Comment: Решил. Встреча с потоками оттянулась до следующей проблемы с I\O :3